# C# RTSP & VLC dotnet

Tags: c#, buffer, rtsp, libvlc, circular-buffer

I'm working with C# and VLC library, and I wonder if there is way to get hands to VLC buffer (netwoking-cache or so).
What I could use, is to save that to my own circular buffer and save it IF needed.
Is this possible, or should I just do it with "manualy" on other stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are audio and video callbacks that allow you to access the raw data using libvlc. It does slow down the perf though, understandably.

This sample https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/-/blob/master/PreviewThumbnailExtractor/Program.cs shows you how to use the video callbacks to extract frames.

This should be a good starting point for achieving whatever you need to do.

Comment: Hi, that is just what I was looking for. I managed to "play" with VLC buffer. Thanks for this!